# SameQ shorthand

Tags: syntax, expression-test

I thought that === is shorthand for SameQ? Then why do these two expressions yield True for one and False for the other?

```
SameQ[((k^2 (k + 1)^2)/4 + (k + 1)^3) == (((k + 1)^2 (k + 2)^2)/4)]
((k^2 (k + 1)^2)/4 + (k + 1)^3) === (((k + 1)^2 (k + 2)^2)/4)
```

Comment: The useless, but correct answer is, because `SameQ[blub]` gives `True` and you don't do what you think you do.

Comment: Replace the `==` in the first line with a comma; `SameQ[a, b]` is equivalent to `a === b`, but `SameQ[a == b]` should evaluate as either `SameQ[True]` or `SameQ[False]`.

Comment: Perhaps for the first line you thought you were doing something like `SameQ @@ (((k^2 (k + 1)^2)/4 + (k + 1)^3) == (((k + 1)^2 (k + 2)^2)/4))`?

Comment: @user16054 Can you elaborate on the difference between `SameQ[False]` and `SameQ[True]`?

Comment: @halirutan Not sure I understand the question; `SameQ[a == b]` will evaluate as either `SameQ[True]` or `SameQ[False]` because `a == b` will usually be transformed into `True` or `False` depending on whether `a` equals `b` or not. `SameQ[a == b]` does not ask Mathematica is `a` and `b` are 'same', it asks if they are equal and passes the result of that question to `SameQ`.

Comment: @user16054 Look, this is exactly why I asked :) 1. No! `SameQ[a == b]` will always evaluate to `True`. Try `SameQ[1 == 1]` and `SameQ[1 == 2]`. 2. Yes, `a==b` *usually* evaluates to `True` or `False`. In the case of the question above, it is not. This is, why the result of the first line is `SameQ[a==b]` with unevaluated equation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `SameQ` is `SameQ[x,y]`, with *two* (or more) arguments and yields `True` if all the arguments are the same.  Your first line is merely `SameQ[.]` with a single argument, which of course yields `True`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is admittedly lacking in detail, but basically

```
SameQ[a, b, c,...]
```

"returns `True` if all the" `a`, `b`, `c`,... "are identical."  In `SameQ[a]`, all the arguments are identical.

Likewise,

```
UnsameQ[a, b, c,...]
```

"gives `True` if no two of"" `a`, `b`, `c`,... "are identical."   In `UnsameQ[a]`, no two of the arguments are identical.

Hence both `SameQ[a]` and `UnsameQ[a]` return `True`, which might seem a paradox if you forget how the quantifiers work.